# Why is delete query not deleting my records while using Room in android?

Tags: android, database, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

This is the code for checking for favourites and adding and removing them.

```
holder.favImageView.setOnClickListener{
                val async = FavouriteDBAsyncTask(context.applicationContext,favouriteEntity,3).execute()
                val result = async.get()
                if(result)
                {
                    // Restaurant is in favourites, so now removing it
                    val async = FavouriteDBAsyncTask(context.applicationContext,favouriteEntity,2).execute()
                    val result = async.get()
                    if(result){
                        println("Removed from favourites")
                        holder.favImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_border_24)
    
                    }else{
                        println("Not removed from Favourites")
                        holder.favImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_24)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Restaurant is not in favourites, so now adding it
                    val async = FavouriteDBAsyncTask(context.applicationContext,favouriteEntity,1).execute()
                    val result = async.get()
                    if(result){
                        println("Added to favourites")
                        holder.favImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_24)
                    }else{
                        println("Not added to Favourites")
                        holder.favImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_border_24)
                    }
    
    
                }
            }
```

The items are being searched and added accordingly. But there's some issue with the delete operation.
When I remove the item, the message "Removed from favourites" gets printed but the item is not removed from favourites. I am printing the list of favourites in a fragment. And there the item appears even after deleting it.

This is my Entity:
@Entity(tableName = "favourites")

```
data class FavouriteEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int = 0 ,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id") var userId : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_id") var favouriteRestaurantId : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_name") var favouriteRestaurantName : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_img") var favouriteRestaurantImage : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_price") var favouriteRestaurantPrice : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fav_restaurant_rating") var favouriteRestaurantRating : String
)
```

This is my Dao :

```
@Dao
interface FavouriteDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(favouriteEntity: FavouriteEntity)

    @Delete
    fun delete(favouriteEntity: FavouriteEntity)


    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE user_id= :userId")
    fun getRestaurantsByUserId(userId : String) : List <FavouriteEntity>

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE fav_restaurant_id = :restaurantId AND user_id = :userId")
    fun getRestaurantByRestaurantIdAndUserId(restaurantId : String,userId: String) : FavouriteEntity

}
```

This is my DB :

```
@Database(entities = [FavouriteEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class FavouriteDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun favouriteDao() : FavouriteDao

}
```

These are my classes for all the async tasks:

```
class FavouriteDBAsyncTask(val context: Context, val favouriteEntity: FavouriteEntity, val mode:Int):AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>() {

    /*
    Mode 1 -> Insert restaurant in Favourites
    Mode 2 -> Delete restaurant from Favourites
    */
    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, FavouriteDatabase::class.java,"favourite_db").build()

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {
       when(mode)
       {
           1 -> {
               // Add restaurants to Favourites
               db.favouriteDao().insert(favouriteEntity)
               db.close()
               return true

           }
           2 -> {
               // Remove restaurants from Favourites
               db.favouriteDao().delete(favouriteEntity)
               db.close()
               return true
           }
           3->{
               // Checking if the restaurant is in favourites

               val favourite : FavouriteEntity? = db.favouriteDao().getRestaurantByRestaurantIdAndUserId(favouriteEntity.favouriteRestaurantId,favouriteEntity.userId)
               db.close()
               return favourite != null
           }
       }
        return false
    }


class RetrieveUserFavourites(val context: Context,val userId:String) : AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<FavouriteEntity>>(){


    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): List<FavouriteEntity> {
        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(context,FavouriteDatabase::class.java,"favourite_db").build()
        return db.favouriteDao().getRestaurantsByUserId(userId)
    }
}
```

The only issue is deletion. Please help.

Comment: In order to @delete to work, your primary id needs to be matched with the record in your db.

Comment: Maybe try using @Query("DELETE FROM FavouriteEntity WHERE id =:id")

Comment: I tried...it's not working